# Colocar e pegar inteiros de arquivo?

Tags: c, arquivo

Tenho duas variáveis inteiras a `rp` e `rc`, e tenho de gravá-las em um arquivo como uma forma de salvar o valor delas, e depois pegá-las e colocá-las em variáveis do tipo `inteiro` para usar no meu programa.

Para gravar em um arquivo, só estou usando um caractere de escape para me informar se o número acabou ou não. Esse caractere é o ponto e virgula `;`.

Estou tentando com o seguinte código, onde `arq` é o meu arquivo:

Para pegar valor:

```
cc = 1;
while(! feof(arq))
{
    get = fgetc(arq);
    if(get != ';')
    {
        if(cc == 1)
        {
            rc = (int)get;
            cc ++;
        }
        else
            rp = (int)get;
        }
}
fclose(arq);
```

Para colocar:

```
fputc(rc, arq);
fputc(';', arq);
fputc(rp, arq);
fputc(';', arq);
```

Eu sei onde está o erro, mas não sei consertar. Ele está pegando o valor `ASCII` do caractere - quando coloco um inteiro ele pega o valor `ASCII` e não o número, e na hora de colocar acontece o mesmo, ele converte o inteiro para `char` e usa o `ASCII`.

Outro problema é que estou levando em consideração apenas números de um algarismo; como faço para levar em consideração números maiores?

Comment: Ja tentou usar fprintf para escrever e fscanf para ler ?

Comment: Consegui com o fprintf e fscanf, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

### A solução prática

Você deve saber um pouco de [manipulação de arquivos](http://www.ime.usp.br/~elo/IntroducaoComputacao/Manipulacao%20de%20arquivo.htm) e IO, e a sintaxe deles no C.
Para ler, você deve apenas checar onde aparecem os `';'`, e nesses intervalos usar fscanf com sintaxe de inteiro. Já para escrever, use fprintf com sintaxe de string, para cada número impresso, imprima o caractere de quebra.

### A solução manual

O primeiro passo é conhecer o tamanho do número. Para isso você itera caractere por caractere até achar o seu caractere de quebra (que no caso, é `';'`). Para isso, você vai pegando caracteres (usando `fgetc`), um por um e compara com o caractere de quebra. Se não for, você deve remover o valor equivalente ao caractere `'0'`. Isso é o que você esqueceu de fazer. E depois adiciona a uma [estrutura FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) (página em inglês). Quando você achar o caractere de quebra, você instancia queue e faz a mesma coisa (esse tipo de coisa é mais fácil de se fazer com orientação a objetos). Depois que você tiver todos esses queues, você usa um conceito do nosso sistema numérico. Por exemplo, `21 = 2*10^1 + 1*10^0`, `432 = 4*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 2*10^0`. Se percebe que os valores são multiplicados por potências de 10, onde o maior dígito é multiplicado por 10^(posição - 1). Então, você usa essa lógica:

```
enquanto o arquivo não estiver no fim:
    caractere = arquivo.le_caractere()
    enquanto caractere não for ';'
        queue.push(caractere - '0')
        caractere = arquivo.le_caractere()
    lista_de_queues += queue

para cada queue em lista_de_queues:
    enquanto houver itens no queue:
        numero += queue.pop() * 10^queue.size()
    lista_de_numeros += numero
```

Note que queue.size() é necessariamente o antigo tamanho - 1, pois pela precedência, pop é chamado primeiro. Dessa maneira você consegue ler os números.

Felizmente, para salvar é mais fácil ainda! Você deve fazer a operação oposta, para extrair um dígito, e depois salvá-lo como um char, somado a `'0'`. O número de dígitos em um número é o logarítmo dele na base 10. Transforma este em inteiro, e vai fazendo o seguinte usando uma [estrutura LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)):

```
for(unsigned i = 1; i <= digitos; i++)
    stack.push( int( (numero % 10^i) / 10^(i-1) ) )
// nesse ponto, estarão na pilha, na ordem inversa. como é uma estrutura LIFO,
// ele vai nos devolver os dígitos na ordem correta
enquanto houver itens na pilha:
arquivo.escreve_caractere(stack.pop() + '0')
```

Números negativos, basta também checar se o primeiro caractere é `'-'`. Se ele for, multiplica o número final por -1.